# How do I download FFmpeg build for windows 7 64 bit? (Zeranoe’s are offline.)

Tags: ffmpeg

There are two windows build on ffmpeg.org

1. gyan.dev
2. BtbN

The first one can’t be downloaded securely.
The second one has lots of files. Which files should I download?

Answer (score 2):

The msg for gyan.dev downloads is a false alarm. All files are delivered via HTTPS. Select Keep instead of Discard.

Chrome shows the same message for [Google Earth](https://support.google.com/earth/thread/64465832?hl=en) downloads as well.
This is apparently an [initiative](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html) by Google to ultimately prevent mixed content downloads in Chrome.